# ngTable filter only works for the first page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, ngtable

Working on an ngTable that has more than 1000 records.
Everything works fine, but the only problem I am facing is the filter.
it only filters text in the active page.
Lets say I am in page 3, and if I search/filter something using a textbox it has to be from page 3 otherwise it will show nothing..

my code is as follow:

```
    $scope.$watch("filter.$", function () {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();});


    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            schoolName: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        }
    },

{
    total: $scope.schoolInfo.length, // length of data
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var filteredData = {};


    //reason I am doing this is to get the data always filtered, no matter what
    var orderedData = $filter('orderBy')($scope.schoolName, params.orderBy());

         params.total(orderedData); // set total for recalc pagination

         $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    },$scope:$scope
    });
```

the sorting works perfect, but its the search only

Search: `<input type="text" ng-model="search.schoolName">`
I also tried ng-model="search"aswell

`<tr ng-repeat="mydata in $data | filter:search">` 
I also tried search:strict

nothing seems to help if someone can please help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example from the ng-table: [Table combining sorting and filtering](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/23)

Try reworking your code to use the code from this example.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your reply back. But the problem is that they are using filter="{ 'name': 'text' }"> which will show a textbox inside the ngTable, but what I want is a textbox, above the table, that can filter the text..I also tried this way but still it does not help..

Comment: @Manam, Could you solve your problem. I am facing a similar problem and looking for solutions.

Comment: Hi @abi1964 the question is, why you want to use ng-Table? What I figured out in that time, was that the solution was to make a filter in the backend? I mean a custom filter, example:

app.filter('wordsFilter', function() {
   return function(items, word) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item.indexOf(word) !== -1){
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    });
 
 <table  ng-repeat="a in as | wordsFilter:textboxfield">
here you can search inside the all array itself, and it is not restricted

Comment: now the question is why you want to use ng-Table? only because it has some pre-defined sorting and thats about it? but what I found was that using ng-table was a mistake, I could use a simple html table and  apply sorting to it easily and limit the page to 20 or 30, it can give me anything I need and I do not need to write all those configurations in the backend.
so what you can do is, in the title bar of your html table, u can put links for sorting, and search can be applied to it easily..
If you need an example let me know..
Good luck with it